# How to get the value of an attribute in cypress

Tags: cypress

I have this HTML element, and I am trying to get the value of `for` attribute

```
<div class="test">
  <label for="aboqo_46" data-test = "user-test" >
```

I want to get retrieve the value in `for` which is `aboqo_46` in the above code. How can this be achieved?

I have tried the following but could not get the values.

```
const result = cy
                 .get('[data-test="user-test"]')
                 .invoke('attr','for')
cy.log(result)
```

The above code logs the result value as `Object{5}`

and

```
cy
 .get('[data-test="user-test"]')
 .its('for')
```

Comment: Did you try after removing the gaps between `data-test = "user-test"`?

Comment: Yes. I am having the same error still

Comment: `.invoke('attr','for')` worked for me. What's your error/result?

Comment: Edited question that displays the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a little off, it's not returning the attribute value it's returning a Chainer object so that Cypress can chain commands.

This will work:

```js
cy.get('[data-test="user-test"]')
  .invoke('attr','for')
  .then(value => cy.log(value))
```